# Setting up SQL query to grab ID from part of a string using join statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables and I am trying to do a join statement on them.

```
SELECT node.title, field_data_body.body_summary, 
  url_alias.alias 
FROM node, field_data_body, url_alias 
WHERE node.nid = field_data_body.entity_id 
 AND node.nid = ".node/".url_alias.source 
 AND field_data_body.bundle='article'
```

The above line doesn't work because of "node.nid = ".node/".url_alias.source" - which isn't the correct way to do the call.

I am trying to compare the nid column in the node table with the source column in the url_alias table. The source column's data is displayed as "node/21" <- so how do I do a company when the "node/" string is in the way?

Comment: I think you are looking for `CONCAT()`. In your example it would look like this `AND node.nid = CONCAT(".node/",url_alias.source)`

Comment: that SQL is a cartesian product, not a join :S

Comment: Also, you will find that your code becomes much more maintanable if you join tables as `Node N Inner Join Field_Data_Body fdb on n.Nid = fdb.Entity_Id`

Comment: @Naryl actually it is a join, they are using older join syntax with the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use REPLACE or LIKE or REGEX:

This uses REPLACE:

```
SELECT node.title, field_data_body.body_summary, url_alias.alias 
FROM node, field_data_body, url_alias 
WHERE node.nid = field_data_body.entity_id 
   AND node.nid = REPLACE(url_alias.source, '.node/', '')
   AND field_data_body.bundle='article'
```

--EDIT

Or as @datasage correctly points out, CONCAT would work too, but I think you need to use single quotes.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT node.title, field_data_body.body_summary, 
  url_alias.alias 
FROM node, field_data_body, url_alias 
WHERE node.nid = field_data_body.entity_id 
 AND node.nid = Concat('.node/.', url_alias.source)
 AND field_data_body.bundle='article'
```

I would also join changing your query to use `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT node.title, field_data_body.body_summary, 
  url_alias.alias 
FROM node
INNER JOIN field_data_body
    on node.nid = field_data_body.entity_id 
INNER JOIN url_alias 
    ON node.nid = Concat('.node/.', url_alias.source)
WHERE field_data_body.bundle='article'
```